# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf CSS file cannot access and have 500 error no template found

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I use Spring Boot 1.4.0 + Thymeleaf, I find the static resources couldn't access and throw the error "template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers".

[Folder structure about my static resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWNlW.png)

[Browser show 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUQeo.png)

From server log, can find the error "template not found". But the URL should be my CSS file location.

```
2018-08-28 21:07:29.826 ERROR 5676 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "Spring Boot Application is available.", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking my source code, I find it's because I have another controller has request mapping to home page and block CSS/JS URL.  After I comment the function test2(), home page can load static resources now.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String test1(){
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping
public String test2(){
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Spring Boot is trying to resolve the resource path as a template.  There may be a conflict with a path to one of your controllers.  Spring Boot by default serves static resources from `/**`.  You can alter this default path in your `application.properties` file with the `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern`.

```
## application.properties

spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

This would result in a new resource path to your static content

boostrap.min.css

`http://localhost:8080/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css`

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I have found the root cause and it isn't due to spring.mvc.static-path-pattern.  I just found that I have another controller and the  @RequestMapping is also direct to index.html.  So this function block all CSS/JS resources request.